# How can I keep CDATA while updating the content of an xml node?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, cdata

In a Ruby script, I want to update the CDATA content while keeping the format as CDATA.

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open('text.xml'))
doc.xpath('//Test').each do |test|
  test.content = 'new string'
end
```

This is my test.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test><![CDATA[<p>Some content</p>]]></Test>
```

Problem is, in my doc `CDATA` converts to `Text`. Is there any way I can keep `CDATA` property?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `Nokogiri::XML::Element#content=` will replace the content of `Test` with a text node (and destroy whatever content used to be there). You need to access your CDATA, then run `content=` on *that*. For example:

```
doc.xpath('//Test').each do |test|
  cdata = test.children.find(&:cdata?)
  cdata.content = 'new string' if cdata
end
```

(It would be more straightforward if you could tell XPath to directly select the CDATA node, but I don't know that it can do that.)